# Mediawiki extension that produces cryptographic hash value of the input string?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm looking for an extension, probably a parser function, that takes an input string (could be any wikitext, and probably needs to support wikitext parsing in the call) and produces the cryptographic hash of the input.

Examples (with Semantic Mediawiki query) usage:

{{#hash: sha1|{{#show: SomeTestingPage|?SomeValue# -}} }}

{{#hash: md5|{{#ask: [[Category: Boats]] [[Displacement::>100000]] [[Purpose::Freighter]]|?format=list|link=none|headers=hide}} }}

Is there anything like this in Mediawiki?

Important: Don't confuse this with the HashTables extension, which implements hash table lookup but doesn't actually produce cryptographic hash values at the page level.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the fact that the cryptographic value of md5 and sha1 is questionable at this point, I'm not aware of an already existing extension that does this. Creating one should be rather easy though, including it being able to parse wikitext.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions this manual gives you a basic example of how this would work, it should be fairly easy to follow.